# Communication between portlets on different pages

Tags: oracle-adf, portal, webcenter

Consider a scenario. I have two WebCenter Portal pages. On one page I have a portlet that takes the location and on the second portlet I have a portlet that displays the weather on the basis of the location entered on the first portlet.
When the user enters location details on the first portlet on the first page and clicks on Submit (the button is inside the portlet itself) the portal page navigates to the result page where the results portlet shows the weather details.

Basically what I want to achieve is:
   1. communication between two portlets on different portal pages
   2. the portal page should navigate to the results page when a request is sent to the portlet.

Comment: Why don't you use database to store/use this info?

Comment: - Do you want the 2 pages to be opened at the same time?
- If you are using portlets why don't you show both at the same page and use contextual events?
- If you are going to switch between two pages why don't you redirect with parameters in the URL?

Comment: Actually I have multiple portlets on the first page. So on the basis of which portlet the user is using, I have to redirect to the results page which has the results portlet. It's like a dashboard. I tried following this:
http://www.ateam-oracle.com/inter-portlet-communication-between-pages/
but I was not able to set up the events in my portlet producer application, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it make more sense to have your portlet be a two page flow where you put info in the first page and then navigate to the results page. This will all be displayed in a region on your portal.

Comment: Actually the requirement is that, on the first page there are multiple portlets, kinda like widgets and on interacting with one, the user is taken to it's results page (portal page). And if the user goes to the results portal page directly, he can see the full version of the portlet there, ie, another jsff in the taskflow.